# How to save DNNRegressor model and load it to predict

Tags: tensorflow

I tried this and got an error like this:

```
Node: 'dnn/hiddenlayer_0/Relu'
In[0] and In[1] has different ndims: [1] vs. [1,1]
     [[{{node dnn/hiddenlayer_0/Relu}}]] [Op:__inference_pruned_1112]
```

here is my code:

```
data = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'age': [40.0, 20.0, 18.0, 15.0, 20.0, 30.0, 21.0, 23.0],
        'click': [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]
    }
)
train, test = train_test_split(data, test_size=0.2)
age = tf.feature_column.numeric_column("age")
feature_columns = [age]
model = tf.estimator.DNNRegressor(feature_columns=feature_columns, hidden_units=[1],
                                  model_dir='./models/dnnregressor')
serving_input_fn = tf.estimator.export.build_parsing_serving_input_receiver_fn(tf.feature_column.make_parse_example_spec([age]))
export_path = model.export_saved_model("./models/dnnregressor_serve", serving_input_fn)
age_feature = tf.train.Feature(float_list=tf.train.FloatList(value=[40]))
simple_feature = tf.train.Features(feature={
    "age": age_feature
})
simple_example = tf.train.Example(features=simple_feature)
serving_model = tf.saved_model.load(export_path)
f = serving_model.signatures['serving_default']
f(inputs=tf.constant(simple_example.SerializeToString()))
```

that is an very simple demo, i just want to check the usage of loading saved mode to predict new examples. then i got an error said at the head of the post.

if anyone can help me!!!

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

change the input from tf.constant(simple_example.SerializeToString()) to
tf.constant([simple_example.SerializeToString()]), will work。

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).